# Passport Transmission Time -- Canadian student visa

Tags: canada, passport-stamps

A few days ago, after a VFS (in Berlin) received my passport for transmission, they sent it to a Canadian embassy (in Vienna), and yesterday (Aug 6) I received a letter through my online portal (at www.cic.gc.ca), implying that my application has been approved, and the letter contains further other information about the date of validity of the visa, etc. I was wondering: when do you think the passport will be sent to the VFS for pick up? I'm asking because I need to travel outside the country, before going to, and soon, to Canada.

Thank you very much for your help.